# Best practices with HDF5 and Datasets

Tags: dataset, hdf5-format

I work with colleagues who rely on `HDF5` as their data interchange format (largely exported from Python's `Pandas`).

Of course we have `Import[]` available for getting this data in, but I would like to work with it in the `Dataset[]` idiom. I was disappointed to see that `SemanticImport[]` doesn't do the job I'd expect here. (You'd sort of hope / expect that importing a `"Dataset"` would, well, map to a `Dataset`, but such are the ways of WRI).

I know I can 'assemble' the `Dataset` from the `HDF5` in a straight-forward way, but was just wondering if anyone had already done the 'heavy lifting' here.

Comment: In [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/92064) I have a section on HDF5, which is based on `Import` / `Export`. This may not be entirely what you are after, but might still be useful. The code I gave there converts between HDF and a tabular list structure, but I also provided functions `tableToDataset` and `datasetToTable` which you can use to convert between `Dataset` and `HDF5`, so you will have to use `tableToDataset @* hdf5ToTable` and `datasetToTable @* tableToHDF5`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Beautiful, I will have a look. Your code is seemingly always useful.

Comment: A followup to the above, in case someone comes looking - Lots of the data I'm getting has so-called Compound data. Mathematica (still) doesn't play nice with compound data, and a few of the custom-whipped MathLink (now called something else) solutions don't seem to like what I have either. So, for now, if you're exchanging Compound data, beware.

Answer (score 3):

You can see:

https://github.com/scotmartin1234/HDF5Mathematica

There are some screenshots about compound datatypes, and you could also download the package and use it.

This is version 2.00 (August 2016) of the package that was originally provided as version 1.00 in July 2011.

Comment: It would be better if instead of posting the exact same thing on a number of different answers, you could tailor each answer to demonstrate how your package works for that particular question. Otherwise, this is rather unproductive.

Comment: Quick note for others looking at this answer, it is, apparently, Windows only and the Github distribution seems to include compiled DLLs and not any source.

Comment: Hi Flip: Mathematica package interfaces between Mathematica and P/Invoke. So: (1) Correct: what is on GitHub includes only Windows DLL. (2) Possible: someone who is good with C can get P/Invoke and other source from HDF group and then compile on Mac and Unix. P/Invoke works in Mac and Unix environments when compiled. An expert "C" user could probably get this to work without too much problem since it's just "compile on my machine". In this case, you'd be all set on Mac or Unix, too. (3)Comment about absence of source is not correct: all Mathematica code is on Gihub; "C" source is on HDF group.